# Pass Multiple Parameters as Additional Parameters in Jasper Reports Integration

Tags: jasper-reports, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm using [opal-consulting Jasper Reports Integration](http://www.opal-consulting.de/apex/f?p=20090928:4:4384823168628130) v 1.3.0 for reporting purposes in my apex application.

When using `show_report` or `get_report` Procedures in there, how could i pass multiple items as `additional parameters` ? comma separated or any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dietmar Aust (the developer of the integration kit) his blog on this subject: http://daust.blogspot.be/2012/08/jasperreportsintegration-passing.html

Copy from his code snippet:

```
-- construct addional parameter list   
l_additional_parameters := 'parameter1=' || apex_util.url_encode(:p1_filter_object_name);
l_additional_parameters := l_additional_parameters || '&parameter2=' || apex_util.url_encode(:p1_filter_object_type);
```

> Why do we use apex_util.url_encode? This is required since we
>   essentially pass the parameters via an url to the j2ee application.